# Работа с DBLookupListBox Delphi 7

Tags: access, ado, delphi

Работаю с базой данных Access. Тема - библиотека.
На `Form1` я хочу в `ListBox` вывести названия имеющихся книг.
Все, что я узнал, это то, что нужно использовать
`DBLookupListBox`. Размещаю на `Form1` `DataSource, ADOQuery, ADOConnection`,
подключаю все, но `DBLookupListBox` остается пустым. Еще на `Form1` у меня имеется `DBGrid`, в который я вывожу другую таблицу из моей БД. Соответственно для вывода
этой таблицы пользуюсь также `DataSource, ADOQuery, ADOConnection` компонентами, но отдельными. Скажите, что я делаю не так.

Answer (score 2):

1. ADOConnection достаточно одного.
2. В DBLookupListBox необходимо указать ListSource (datasource от таблицы книг), а также ListField (Поле которое будет отображаться в списке BookName, например). Для начала.

Что вы делаете не так сложно понять, потому что вы не описали что вы хотите получить в результате - редактирование, фильтрацию, просто отображение названия всех книг...

Comment: Просто отображение названия всех книг. Свойства ListSource и ListField указываю.

Comment: ADOQuery.Active? Попробуйте сначала в гриде отобразить ваши данные потом в листбоксе.